# php ajax chat problem

Tags: php, ajax

This is my php code...........

```
$root = "http://localhost/";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mychat WHERE (too='$mid' AND froom='$uid') OR (too='$uid' AND froom='$mid') ORDER BY id ASC");
    while($ro=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $from = $ro['froom'];
        $to = $ro['too'];
        $text = $ro['text'];
        $time = $ro['time'];
        $last_count = $ro['last_count'];
        echo '<li class="chat_li">
        <font face="MS Sans Serif" size="1">'.$froom.'</font></a> says: &nbsp; '.wordwrap($text, 1000,"<br>\n", true).'
            <br><font size="1" color="#777777">'.$time.'</font>
        </li>';
}
```

but it is showing only user1 name and all text but not showing the appropriate user with text msg............

how can i fix that

my database table.........

```
id, froom, too, text, time
```

and here is my output..........
if user1 types........[ ssss] and user2 types.....[ 1244]

output is always.

user1says: ssss
1min ago

user1says: 1244
50sec ago

Comment: Your code appears to be missing some ?> and <?php tags around the various bits of HTML? Can you maybe also paste an example of the output you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$root = "http://localhost/";
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mychat WHERE (too='$mid' AND froom='$uid') OR (too='$uid' AND froom='$mid') ORDER BY id ASC");

    $ro= mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    for($i=0;$i< count($ro);$i++)
    {        
            $to[$i] = $ro[$i]['too'];
            $last_count[$i] = $ro[$i]['last_count'];
            echo '<li class="chat_li">

            <font face="MS Sans Serif" size="1">'.$ro[$i]['froom'].'</font></a> says:.wordwrap($ro[$i]['text'], 1000,"<br>\n", true).'
                    <br><font size="1" color="#777777">'.$ro[$i]['time'].'</font>
            </li>

}
```